# Link to particular tab in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I have a sample page with three tabs (`tabs.html`). Tabs are displayed as follows:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('tab_1', 'content_1');" id="tab_1" class="active">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('tab_2', 'content_2');" id="tab_2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:tabSwitch('tab_3', 'content_3');" id="tab_3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

The JavaScript used to switch tabs is:

```js
function tabSwitch(active, number, tab_prefix, content_prefix) {
    for (var i = 1; i < number+1; i++) {  
        document.getElementById(content_prefix+i).style.display = 'none';  
        document.getElementById(tab_prefix+i).className = '';  
    }  
    document.getElementById(content_prefix+active).style.display = 'block';  
    document.getElementById(tab_prefix+active).className = 'selected';      
}
```

Now, by default, when I link to `tabs.html`, the first tab is set to active. Is it possible to create a link from another site that links to `tabs.html` and forces the second or third tab to be active?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.onload = function(){
    if (location.hash !== "")
    {
        var page = location.hash.match(/[0-9]/);
        tabSwitch('tab_'+page, 'content_'+page);
    }
}
```

That should work for setting the correct tab.  Then a link would be something like `http://www.example.com/tabs.html#tab_1`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm getting "Document body is null" error in javascript console.

Comment: @mkas your page does have a body doesn't it? O_o

Comment: Sure, could you please have a look at [my site](http://krill.olimp-labs.com/gold-krill.html), because I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Try using `document.onload` instead of `document.body.onload`.

Answer (score 0):

yes just append your options to the url like `tabs.html?1` and then check `window.location.search.substr(1)` for your tabnumber onload

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the tab you want to add from the hash like `tabs.html#tab1`. Then on a code block that run on the page onload do something like this:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash == "#tab1")
    tabSwitch('tab_1', 'content_1');
else if (hash == "#tab2")
    tabSwitch('tab_2', 'content_2');
else if (hash == "#tab3")
    tabSwitch('tab_3', 'content_3');
```

I don't know if you're doing it by itself to learn javascript, but there is a jquery plugin named [jQuery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) that does exactly what you're trying to do.